# discord.js Greeting message not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was following the discord.js docs and when I tried to test the greeting thing the message didn't send. The channel is right, I even tried doing it with the channel ID (with different code), I also tried just sending a direct message. No error appears, the console is just empty and the message doesn't appear.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
    if (!channel) return;

    message.channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for "cache" in `guildMemberAdd`, that's why the channel was not found. 
The `message` variable was also not defined.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Comment: I already tried doing it without the message.channel.send insted using just channel.send. I copied the example to then modify it for my liking, but it doesnt seem to work still.

Comment: Plus, the example you added doesn't work either. Here's the full code if you need it https://hastebin.com/ucoseyuwev.js

Comment: @Ranbee What is happening in this code exactly? Why do you have two clients, one with uppercase one without? Did you even review your code before posting it here?

Comment: That's one problem that I already fixed before when I noticed it. I got confused a bit, but this is not the thing I ask for help with.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem and for me it wasn't a problem in the code itself, I just gave the bot every single permission on the category of the welcome channel as well as the welcome channel itself.
It could also be that you have something else as the const name instead of 'client'.

Comment: The bot has every single permission on the server, and the general channel isnt even restricted. It can send messages there, if it couldnt it would throw an error.